# What is the all() function in RelatedManager?

Tags: python, django

In django `ManyToManyField()`, when you refer to it, it is going to return a `RelatedManager`.

If you want to get the actual objects, you have to call `all()`, however I don't see any documents describing this behaviour, is `RelatedManager` a kind of `QuerySet`? Otherwise, why there can be an `all()` method?

And after calling `all()`, is it going to return a `QuerySet`?

Answer (score 1):

The `RelatedManager` is a `Manager` and not a `QuerySet`, but it implements the database-abstraction API and because of that it has all the `QuerySet` methods such as `get()`, `exclude()`, `filter()` and `all()`.

The difference in calling `all()` in a `RelatedManager` is that it actually performs a query in the database.

The `all()` method returns a `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/) function to a `RelatedManager` object. Yes, it will return a QuerySet, you can perform `.all()`, `.filter()`, etc.